# Why is bundleConfig ignoring my include directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle

In my BundleConfig.cs file I am trying to include all of my angularjs files in one step. I have:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
     "~/Scripts/angular.js",
     "~/Scripts/angular-*"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/App").IncludeDirectory(
     "~/App", "*.js", true));
```

The first include works fine. It includes all of the angular files; however, the second include does not. When I go to sources in the browser it does not show up.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Your probably do not have an `App` folder in your root or the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @beautifulcoder the app folder is in my root and intellisense recognizes it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the step that I missed was adding:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
```

To the _Layout.cshtml page.

Now everything works as intended